# How to override AutoMapper's config on single property?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper 12.0.0 to fix wrong string property values. In the example below I have class with some string properties and for all properties except one I need to perform `.Trim('*')`. And for the remaining one I need to perform `.ToUpper()` instead of `.Trim('*')`.

The problem is that I don't know how to tell AutoMapper not to use `CreateMap<string, string>()` mapping configuration on single property and use another rule instead. It just always applies  both rules. And if I add `.Ignore()` or `.Condition(_ => false)`, it just ignores property at all and puts `null` instead.

Really don't want to set up mapping for each property manually, because in classes in my real project there are just too many properties, and special rules are needed just for few of them.

Have any ideas how to achieve that in AutoMapper?

```
using AutoMapper;

var data = new MyClass
{
    String1 = "***trim that***",
    String2 = "***trim also that***",
    String3 = "***and trim this***",
    SpecialString = "***don't trim, but make in uppercase***"
};
var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg=>cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>()));
var result = mapper.Map<MyClass>(data);

// [trim that] - ok
Console.WriteLine($"[{result.String1}]");
// [trim also that] - ok
Console.WriteLine($"[{result.String2}]");
// [and trim this] - ok
Console.WriteLine($"[{result.String3}]");
// [DON'T TRIM, BUT MAKE IN UPPERCASE] - Not ok, should be [***DON'T TRIM, BUT MAKE IN UPPERCASE***]
Console.WriteLine($"[{result.SpecialString}]");


public class MyClass
{
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }
    public string String3 { get; set; }
    public string SpecialString { get; set; }
}

public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing<TrimTypeConverter>();
        CreateMap<MyClass, MyClass>()
            .ForMember(x => x.SpecialString, expr => expr.ConvertUsing(new ToUpperValueConverter()));
    }
}

public class ToUpperValueConverter : IValueConverter<string, string>
{
    public string Convert(string sourceMember, ResolutionContext context) => sourceMember?.ToUpper();
}

public class TrimTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, string>
{
    public string Convert(string source, string destination, ResolutionContext context) => source?.Trim('*');
}
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks for suggestion - it definitely looks like better way to do simple type mapping, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem - I tried and still both rules apply for SpecialString field

Comment: Yes, because it's called _Auto_Mapper :) You can use `Ignore` and `AfterMap`. Transformers are more flexible than maps in the way they're applied, but indeed, they compose.

Answer (score 0):

I am not crazy about this solution, but you asked for it so here it is:

One way of going about this would be to create a custom converter for all objects and provide logic for string properties. You can then provide a list of exceptions to modify the behavior:

```
public class CustomConverter : ITypeConverter<object, object>
{
    private IDictionary<Type, IEnumerable<string>> _exceptions;

    public CustomConverter(IDictionary<Type, IEnumerable<string>> exceptions)
    {
        _exceptions = exceptions;
    }

    public object Convert(object source, object destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var type = source.GetType();
        if (destination == null)
            destination = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        
        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(source);
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {                        
                if(_exceptions.ContainsKey(type) && _exceptions[type].Contains(property.Name))
                {
                    property.SetValue(destination, ((string)value)?.ToUpper());
                }
                else
                {
                    property.SetValue(destination, ((string)value)?.Trim('*'));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Any other property picked up by reflection.
                //Just copy over whatever the value is.
                property.SetValue(destination, value);
            }
        }
        return destination;
    }
}
```

Then on the mapping profile:

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    var exceptions = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<string>>()
    {
        { typeof(MyClass), new[] { "SpecialString" } }
    };

    var converter = new CustomConverter(exceptions);
    CreateMap<object, object>().ConvertUsing(converter);            
}
```

The result:

> ```
> [trim that]
> [trim also that]
> [and trim this]
> [***DON'T TRIM, BUT MAKE IN UPPERCASE***]
> ```

Please note that this is a simplistic version only so you may need to worry about special cases.

Comment: The question directly addresses this approach as undesirable.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @JuanR. Perhaps, to write something custom like this would be the only option

Comment: @DaniilB that seems to be the case but maybe someone else out there has a better idea. Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it solves your problem.