# Override Automapper TypeConverter

Tags: c#, automapper, typeconverter

I have created an Automapper 12 TypeConverter for <DateTime, DateTime> that converts the source DateTime to UTC and removes the time portion of the DateTime object so that we store just the Date portion in the database.

```
this.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeConverterForUniversalTime());

public class DateTimeConverterForUniversalTime : ITypeConverter<DateTime, DateTime>
{
  public DateTime Convert(DateTime source, DateTime destination, ResolutionContext context)
  {
    
    var convertedSource = new DateTime(source.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return convertedSource.Date;
  }
}
```

However, I have 1 class where I still want the time portion of its DateTime property.  How can I override the type converter for this one property on one class?  I still want to convert it to UTC before storing it in the database (or convert to local time on the way back out), but I don't want the time portion being removed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182654/how-to-override-automappers-config-on-single-property) post, but I *DO NOT* want to write an <object, object> converter that is then being run for every conversion, just to check if this one field on one class is being converted.

Comment: Try a value transformer instead. That's more flexible as to where it applies.

Comment: What information do you have available in the `ResolutionContext`?

Comment: @Progman - only a Dictionary called `Items`, the current `Mapper` and the `InstanceCache`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - The [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-transformers.html) on Value Transformers is a bit light.  Any chance you can provide an example?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/ValueTransformers.cs). If all else fails, you can `Ignore` and use `AfterMap` for that particular case.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - can you submit as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted?  I tried ValueTransformers on the Mapping and it works perfectly, as long as you don't need BOTH transformers on the same model, which in my case, currently I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a map you can use a [value transformer](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html).
The advantage is that they're more flexible about where they apply.
A map is always global, it applies everywhere.